# PDF Portfolio Icons are PS instead of PDF when using iText7

Tags: powershell, pdf, pdf-generation, itext7, acrobat

When I make the portfilio using my script the file icons in the Portfolio show as a PS icon instead of the Adobe PDF icon when I make it with Adobe Acrobat. Also for some reason, the the size of the PDF files inside the portfolio made with iText7 show as 0 bytes until they're edited.
[PS Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TABS9.png)
[Adobe PDF Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlLfg.png)

I've tried looking at the metadata between them and I don't see anything that should make a difference. I'm not sure how to go about fixing it or even if it can be fixed.
Here's my current code:

```
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf
using namespace iText.Pdfa
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.Collection
Using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.COllection.PdfCollectionItem
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.Filespec
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.WriterProperties
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.Version
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfCatalog.SetPageLayout
using namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf.Collection.PdfCollectionSort
using namespace iText.Layout
using namespace iText.Layout.Element
Import-Module "\\Mac\Home\Downloads\ds584+rob portfolio\itext7module.1.0.34\IText7Module.psd1"
$pdfCoverImage = "\\Mac\Home\Downloads\abobeportfoliocoverimage.pdf"
$pdfFiles = Get-ChildItem "\\Mac\Home\Downloads\input" -Filter "test*.pdf"
$pdfFilePath2 = "\\Mac\Home\Downloads\test.pdf"
$pdfFileName2 = $pdfFilePath2.Substring($pdfFilePath2.LastIndexOf('\') + 1)
$StampingProperties = [StampingProperties]::new()
$writerProperties = [WriterProperties]::new()
[void]$writerProperties.SetPdfVersion([PdfVersion]::PdfVersion.PDF_1_7)
ForEach($pdfFile in $pdfFiles){
$pdfReader = [PdfReader]::new($pdfCoverImage)
$pdfFileOut = "\\Mac\Home\Downloads\output\" + $pdfFile.BaseName + " + " + $pdfFileName2 
$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pdfFileOut, $writerProperties)
$collection = [PdfCollection]::new()
$pdf = [PdfDocument]::new($pdfReader,$pdfWriter,$StampingProperties.useAppendMode())
[void]$pdf.GetCatalog().SetCollection($collection)
$PdfFileSpec = [PdfFileSpec]::CreateEmbeddedFileSpec($pdf, $pdfFile.FullName, $pdfFile.Name, "")
$PdfFileSpec2 = [PdfFileSpec]::CreateEmbeddedFileSpec($pdf, $pdfFilePath2, $pdfFileName2, "")
$pdf.AddFileAttachment($pdfFile.Name, $PdfFileSpec)
$pdf.AddFileAttachment($pdfFileName2, $PdfFileSpec2)
[void]$collection.SetView([PdfCollection]::TILE)
[void]$collection.SetInitialDocument($PdfFile.Name)
$sort = [PdfCollectionSort]::new([PdfCollectionField]::FILENAME)
[void]$collection.SetSort($sort)
$pdf.Close()
}
```